# How to Create Parallax effect on Recycler View Item on Scroll ?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

Hey I have a recycler view and each item of the recycler view Contain ImageView Which in FrameLayout and the image Stretched to fit all the item Size
What i want to do to create Parallax effect on the Recycler View Item image

that i can to move the image to show hidden part of it when i scroll up and down

Like this [Tutorial](http://www.michaelbabiy.com/parallax-scroll-view-in-swift/) in swift

What i did here on Recycler View scroll

```
  events_list.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            final DynamicImageView imageView = (DynamicImageView) recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    Animation a = new Animation() {

                        @Override
                        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                            params.topMargin = (int)(-50 * interpolatedTime);
                            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                        }
                    };
                    a.setDuration(100); // in ms
                    imageView.startAnimation(a);

                } else if (dy < 0) {
                    Animation a = new Animation() {

                        @Override
                        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                            params.topMargin = (int)(50 * interpolatedTime);
                            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                        }
                    };
                    a.setDuration(100); // in ms
                    imageView.startAnimation(a);
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

i know that this code not the optimal solution it also need to check all visible item not the first one but my problem here that i i change the margin of the image view  i'm getting a free spaces between items and the animation doesn't works perfectly
any help?

Comment: you'll probably just want to make your own layout / view and not work with the scroll listener. Overwrite the `onLayout` method and you're set. you can then, depending on the views position, draw the imageview yourself, parallaxing it

Comment: Thanks @bleeding182 you are right the library that i found work in this way thanks Again

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i found this [Library](https://github.com/Narfss/ParallaxEverywhere) at achieve what i exactly want

how it used

```
<com.fmsirvent.ParallaxEverywhere.PEWImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        pew:block_parallax_x="true"
        pew:reverse="reverseY"

        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
```